# How to work on user permission .net core mvc

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am working on HR employee module and I am stuck in user permission authorization and don't know how do do it. I have attached an example image. Can someone help to build something like that for user permission?

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited your question so it is easier to read. Like this your question might not get many answers. What have you tried so far? Can you show us the code you already have? Where and how exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claims Register

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string 
returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = 
 model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {

            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new 
 System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
            await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new 
  System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Developer"));


            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
            // Send an email with this link
            //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
            //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
            //    $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

You can start for this..

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>


options.UseSqlServer
(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    // Adjustment to params from the default settings
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


    services.AddMvc();

    #region Configure all Claims Policies

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        //options.AddPolicy("Administrators", policy => 
policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
        options.AddPolicy("Administrators", policy => 
policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")); // This works the same as 
                                                //the above code
        options.AddPolicy("Name", policy => 
policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Bhail"));

    });
    #endregion

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
 public IActionResult Index() { 
    return View(); }

[Authorize(Policy = "Administrators")]
public IActionResult About()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}

[Authorize(Policy = "Name")]
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}

public IActionResult Error()
{
    return View();
}
}
```

LOGIN

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model,string returnUrl)
{
var user = UserManager.Find(model.Email, model.Password);
if(user!=null)
{
    var ident = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, 
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    ident.AddClaims(new[] {
        new Claim("MyClaimName","MyClaimValue"),
        new Claim("YetAnotherClaim","YetAnotherValue"),
    });
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
        new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, 
        ident);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
return View(model);
}
```

Comment: can you help me with claim based authorization how i can work with it? i just need a start

Comment: thanks a lot for you reply how i can make it dynamically for example lets take employee page in which i have employee list. i want to create permission page in which i should have check boxes for permission (edit, add, delete, view), so for example if i choose view only user should not able to view emoloyee list....?

Comment: you have to create an Action for each, Edit, Add,Delete... and put the decorator of the authorize Policy like ive done with Contact or About at homeController.

Comment: Check it: http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-identity-role-claims

Comment: i already have controller for edit add delete until i understand but how its gonna work with html checkboxes?

Comment: When you call one Action from Html, the controller check the decorator allowed and the claims of the user asigned at Login, then enter or not if it got the permissons

Comment: Example here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36959.asp-net-core-mvc-authentication-and-claim-based-authorisation-with-asp-net-identity-core.aspx

Comment: ok thanks a lot i will try to implement with this one if i stuck somewhere will come back to you

Comment: ok vote me for all this time helping you :)

Comment: hey the link you sent me it helped me a lot and i successfully implemented claim based authorization in my application, now when i add permission for example that user can't add new employee, when user click on add button its redirect to the page in which its written "you dont have permission". Can you guide me something in whch links hide based on permission?i mean if user dont have permission to add new employee i need to hide that button

Comment: Yes, you only have to check if him have permisson at view. @if(gotPermissons){ <button> }