# How to add user roles upon registrations in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In the registration page, I want to have a dropdown list to add Roles that are already defined in the startup.cs, and I am unable to find something like this for asp.net core.

I have tried the following method that was a part of a tutorial for ASP.NET, but it seems like it's not working for the CORE.

Here is the code:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(User.Id, model.RoleName);

                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                var callbackUrl = Url.EmailConfirmationLink(user.Id, code, Request.Scheme);
                await _emailSender.SendEmailConfirmationAsync(model.Email, callbackUrl);

              //  await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I am getting an error on the line `result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(User.Id, model.RoleName);`
 where it says `'ClaimsPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'ClaimsPrincipal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I don't even know what ClaimsPrincipal is.

Any help, please?

Comment: Check it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069949/how-to-work-on-user-permission-net-core-mvc/49070483#49070483

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(User.Id, model.RoleName);
```

Should be:

```
result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.RoleName);
```

Notice the use of your lowercase `user` variable, rather than the controller property `User`. `User` is the claims principal representation of the logged in user, and doesn't have an `Id` property. Hence, the error.

Comment: And, that would be because the first param is not supposed to be the id, but rather the whole user object, i.e. `user` instead of `user.Id`. This is all documented. Take the time to actually read the exceptions. Sometimes, they're obtuse, but in this case, both were pretty explicit, telling you exactly what you needed to fix.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. For future reference, could you or someone provide tips or links for how to get what i want in the documentation and how to actually READ the documentation. I'm just starting out with this. Thank you.

Comment: The .NET documentation has improved dramatically over the last year or two. It is now much more comprehensive and straight forward: https://learn.microsoft.com. Your best bet usually is to just Google the method or exception you need help with, though. Additionally, everything is available on GitHub now, so it's often helpful to just look at the source directly: https://github.com/aspnet

Comment: @ChrisPratt in AccountController _userManager in private Field and sometimes may not be initialized ,you should use UserManager not _userManager :)

Comment: @AminM: This is for Core. Things are a little different. The UserManager is injected, not newed up via a prop getter.